# How to remove margins around background color

Tags: html, css

For some reason the code below will output a black background that has white margins around it. I even have margin: 0px but for some reason the margins are still there. I have tried to set all the other elements to 0 margin but that didn't work either.

```css
.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hello My name is Ben</h1>
  <p>A Web Developer </p>
</section>
```

```
.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted that would cause white margins to appear. You probably have other style-rules elsewhere that are affecting your page's appearance.

Comment: If you see the code in chrome devtools you will find that there is `margin:8px` given to `<body>` the answer given by `hiren` and `kp86284` should do the job.

Comment: To add to what others have already said - many browser render the "default" values of certain things slightly different from one another. In this case, the `<body>` has a default margin built in. There are libraries out there such as normalize.css that try to address this. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
    <h1>Hello My name is Ben</h1>
    <p>A Web Developer </p>
  </section>
```

```
add in your css :-

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding `border: 0` to your style rules. It sounds like by 'margin' you mean [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

It's likely something else on the page is setting a border. You really should share a full example though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,
Add this to your css

```
body{
    margin: 0%;
}
```

It will fit background color to the border.